# Change name of copied tab

Tags: vba, excel

I have some vba code below which I am looping through a directory of template files, opening any file that has a .xlsx extension and copying to the wbTarget workbook the "Reporting" tab from each workbook.  I can copy the worksheet but I would like to change the name of the tab that has been copied in to the variable `Filename`.

```
    Public Sub CopySheets()

    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Path As String
    Path = "C:\combine\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
    Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook

    Do While Len(Filename) > 0  
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
        Sheet = 2
        wbk.Sheets("Reporting").Copy After:=Workbooks("Combined.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("Combined.xlsm").Sheets.Count)

        '>>change name of copied tab here<<   

        wbk.Close True
        Filename = Dir
        Sheet = Sheet + 1
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

After this line

```
wbk.Sheets("Reporting").Copy After:=Workbooks("Combined.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("Combined.xlsm").Sheets.Count)
```

try

```
ActiveSheet.Name = "myname" '<== replace with whatever name you want to assign to the tab
```

Answer (score 0):

After this line

```
`wbk.Sheets("Reporting").Copy After:=Workbooks("Combined.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("Combined.xlsm").Sheets.Count) `
```

try this

```
`Workbooks("Combined.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("Combined.xlsm").Sheets.Count-1)  = "NewName"`
```